# C recursively flattening nodelist

Tags: c, recursion, pass-by-reference, valgrind, dataflow

I'm getting some C memory errors I am really struggling a lot to figure out. I'm pretty new to C, and we're using it in compiler design, and I absolutely love the language, pointers are really fun to play with.

The task I am trying to accomplish is recursively descending a tree and simplifying it, and I'm stuck on lists.

The list is defined as following: statement_list --> statement_list statement | statement

The goal is to make a statement_list node with many statement children, flattening the recursively defined structure

The idea is to exploit the structure of the list as following: When finding a statement list I define an array of pointers, then descend to the  left statement_list node until there is only one child, then allocating the array and fill in the statements as I ascend. This way I will only have to allocate once. I hope the code will make it a little clearer:

```
// Takes a list, truncates all list children into a node array
void list_flatten ( Node_t* root, int depth ){
fprintf(stderr, "## List flatten ##\n");

// We allocate a reference to the array
Node_t** array = malloc(sizeof(Node_t**));
int size = 0;

// We start the recursive call
left_flatten( root, 0, &array, &size, depth );

root->children = array;
root->n_children = size;
}


void left_flatten ( Node_t* root, int counter, Node_t*** array_ptr, int* size, int depth ){

// This is for testing
if(outputStage == 4)
    printf( "%*cSimplify %s \n", depth, ' ', root->nodetype.text );

// We increment size 
(*size)++;

// If there is only one child we know we are at the last statement_list, so we extract the statement
if(root->n_children == 1){
    node_t** array  = *array_ptr;
    *array = malloc((*size)*sizeof(Node_t*));
    Node_t* test = root->children[0]->simplify(root->children[0], depth + 1);

    fprintf(stderr, "Adding a %s to index %d\n", root->children[0]->nodetype.text, 0 );
    *(array + 0) = test;
}

// If else we keep descending
else{
    // We make a nother recursive call
    left_flatten( root->children[0], counter + 1, array_ptr, size, depth + 1);

    // The recursive call wil lhave allocated the memory we need
    node_t** array  = *array_ptr;
    int index = *size - counter - 1;

    // We fire off the recursive simplification for the right child
    Node_t* test = root->children[1]->simplify(root->children[1], depth + 1);

    fprintf(stderr, "Adding a %s to index %d\n", root->children[1]->nodetype.text, index );
    *(array + index) = test;
}
}
```

It did what it was supposed to in 28 of the 30 programs I tried to parse, running into some mysterious seg faults, so I tried to use valgrind to find out what was happening, and got the log below:

```
## List flatten ##
Adding a STATEMENT to index 0
Adding a STATEMENT to index 1
==19604== Invalid write of size 8
==19604==    at 0x406CF8: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:271)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==    by 0x406C63: left_flatten (simplifynodes.c:261)
==19604==  Address 0x520d5b8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==19604==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19604==    by 0x406AFD: list_flatten (simplifynodes.c:228)
==19604==    by 0x40691B: simplify_list (simplifynodes.c:176)
==19604==    by 0x4067C5: simplify_function (simplifynodes.c:75)
==19604==    by 0x406A33: left_flatten_null (simplifynodes.c:211)
==19604==    by 0x406964: list_flatten_null (simplifynodes.c:197)
==19604==    by 0x4068F5: simplify_list_with_null (simplifynodes.c:168)
==19604==    by 0x406E21: simplify_children (simplifynodes.c:296)
==19604==    by 0x4065E4: simplify_default (simplifynodes.c:28)
==19604==    by 0x4010BE: main (vslc.c:95)
==19604== 
Adding a STATEMENT to index 2
Adding a STATEMENT to index 3
Adding a STATEMENT to index 4
Adding a STATEMENT to index 5
Adding a STATEMENT to index 6
Adding a STATEMENT to index 7
Adding a STATEMENT to index 8
Adding a STATEMENT to index 9
Adding a STATEMENT to index 10
Adding a STATEMENT to index 11
Adding a STATEMENT to index 12
Adding a STATEMENT to index 13


// Takes a list, truncates all list children into a node array
void list_flatten ( Node_t* root, int depth ){
    fprintf(stderr, "## List flatten ##\n");

    // We allocate a reference to the array
    Node_t** array = malloc(sizeof(Node_t**));
    int size = 0;

    // We start the recursive call
    left_flatten( root, 0, &array, &size, depth );

    root->children = array;
    root->n_children = size;
}


void left_flatten ( Node_t* root, int counter, Node_t*** array_ptr, int* size, int depth ){

    // This is for testing
    if(outputStage == 4)
        printf( "%*cSimplify %s \n", depth, ' ', root->nodetype.text );

    // We increment size 
    (*size)++;

    // If there is only one child we know we are at the last statement_list, so we extract the statement
    if(root->n_children == 1){
        node_t** array  = *array_ptr;
        *array = malloc((*size)*sizeof(Node_t*));
        Node_t* test = root->children[0]->simplify(root->children[0], depth + 1);

        fprintf(stderr, "Adding a %s to index %d\n", root->children[0]->nodetype.text, 0 );
        *(array + 0) = test;
    }

    // If else we keep descending
    else{
        // We make a nother recursive call
        left_flatten( root->children[0], counter + 1, array_ptr, size, depth + 1);

        // The recursive call wil lhave allocated the memory we need
        node_t** array  = *array_ptr;
        int index = *size - counter - 1;

        // We fire off the recursive simplification for the right child
        Node_t* test = root->children[1]->simplify(root->children[1], depth + 1);

        fprintf(stderr, "Adding a %s to index %d\n", root->children[1]->nodetype.text, index );
        *(array + index) = test;
    }
}
```

The program also explodes horribly when I try to free nodes as well, and I assume this has to do with the underlying memory issues. I originally implemented it with regular double pointers but I got the same result.

I will likely just redo it in a less efficient way as we have a delivery deadline and it's graded, but I really do want to figure out what is going on here as it might add some insight. If anyone wants all of the code just say so and I'll upload it. PS first post, if I'm breaking any sort of code of conduct let me know :)

Comment: I'd suggest that since you already know where there error is based on the valgrind output that you step through the code with gdb. You will likely see that you are not indexing something correctly.

Comment: I'll take a look at it with gdb, but I need t get this thing done first before I start learning, but I'll update when I do find out what is causing it